# Migrate library implementation for cassandra with multiple host ip's

Tags: go, cassandra, schema-migration, golang-migrate

I am trying to use golang-migrate library for cassandra migrations.

In the [Docs](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/tree/master/database/cassandra), they have mentioned to use cassandra url like this

> cassandra://host:port/keyspace?param1=value&param2=value2

We will be having more than  one host for cassandra.

Do I need to loop for each host and run migrations separately? or is there is any other way?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way, as library author is using `url.Parse` for parsing the `URL` as web doesn't allow multiple 'ip''s to be included in single `URL`, you need to loop over each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ALTER` should be realised / replicated across the cluster. Migrate uses the highest level of consistency (`ALL` / https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshConsistency.html) so it's the best choice if your hosts are within a cluster.

If the hosts aren't in a cluster, then hand rolling and applying the migrations for each host is the only option.